# Temporarily enabling a blacklisted kernel module from the cli

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

I have disabled a kernel module on my system

```
>> uname -a
Linux zyx 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.5-1 (2016-02-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux

>> cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf 

# Disable WebCam
blacklist uvcvideo
```

**Question**

Is it possible to temporarily enable a blacklisted kernel module from the commandline? If so, how? If not what other options are there to disable the module at boot time?

I have tried the following, which didn't let me use my webcam.

> > sudo modprobe uvcvideo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have thought `modprobe` would ignore the blacklist, unless `-b` was specified...

In any case, the following should work whatever the blacklist settings are:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvcvideo.ko
```

If the modules `uvcvideo` depends on haven't already been loaded, you'll need to take care of that too (and then load `uvcvideo` again):

```
sudo modprobe videodev
sudo modprobe videobuf2-core
sudo modprobe usbcore
sudo modprobe media
sudo modprobe videobuf2-malloc
```

You can find this out for any module using `modinfo`:

```
/sbin/modinfo uvcvideo
```